# AWS Data Pipeline - csv(s3) to RDS Oracle

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline, dms

I want to load my s3 csv file data in RDS Oracle existing table. But in the console, i am not able to find any templates for it. Does it supports oracle also.

[image: This image i have taken from console] If yes, How can i achieve this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's seeking commercial support.

Comment: Not commerical.. i am looking for the solution where i need to create a pipeline to achieve the data migration.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to adjust the templates for the Oracle database.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-rdsdatabase.html

> For the Oracle engine, the jdbcDriverJarUri field is required and you can specify the following driver: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html.

Comment: You mean i need to create this custom template. Can you just tell me the steps needed to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried already and why didn't that work?

Comment: I was looking for different approaches. I found data pipeline but didnt saw any template for oracle. I tried using lambda but my file size is more than 500 mb. So thats not a good option.also s3-rds integrations. Aws data pipeline looks ok to my req, but there is no template defined.

Comment: @Nimmo no, I meant what have you done already to modify the template and why didn&#39;t they work?

Comment: No idea from where i need to start to modify this template.